# Vue Frontend - Multer Express - Req.File is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, multer

I have been debugging this all day and am finally out of googling options.

I have a Vue3 frontend that receives an image and is supposed to send said image to the backend. I have verified that the image is, in fact, being sent, but the file object in Multer is showing undefined every time regardless of what the front-end / network says is being sent.

Here's my code

Frontend

```
<template>
  <div class="flex justify-center">
    <div class="mb-3 w-96">
      <label for="formFile" class="form-label inline-block mb-2 text-gray-700"
        >Upload a new profile picture</label
      >
      <input
        class="form-control block w-full px-3 py-1.5 text-base font-normal text-gray-700 bg-white bg-clip-padding border border-solid border-gray-300 rounded transition ease-in-out m-0 focus:text-gray-700 focus:bg-white focus:border-blue-600 focus:outline-none"
        type="file"
        @change="onSelect"
        id="formFile"
      />
      <span class="message"> {{ message }} </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import axios from "redaxios";
export default {
  name: "FileUpload",
  props: {
    user: Array | Object,
  },
  created() {},
  data() {
    return {
      file: "",
      message: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onSelect(e) {
      this.file = e.target.files[0] || e.dataTransfer.files;
      if (this.file.length) return;
      const formData = new FormData();
      console.log(this.file);
      formData.append("id", this.user.id);
      formData.append("file", this.file);
      //formData.set("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
      console.log(formData);
      try {
        axios
          .post("http://localhost:3669/uploadPhoto", formData)
          .then((res) => {
            this.message = "Uploaded successfully!";
          });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        this.message = "Something went wrong uploading your photo!";
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Backend

```
const fileFilter = (req: express.Request, file: File, cb) => {
    const allowedTypes = /jpeg|jpg|png|gif/;
    const extname = allowedTypes.test(path.extname(file.name).toLowerCase());
    const mimetype = allowedTypes.test(file.type);
    if (!mimetype && extname) {
        const error = new Error("Incorrect Filetype");
        error.name = "INCORRECT_FILETYPE";
        return cb(error, false);
    }
    cb(null, true);
}

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        if (req.body.id) {
            cb(null, `./public/photos/${req.body.id}`)
        } else {
            cb(null, "./public/photos");
        }
    },
    filename: function (req, file: File, cb) {
      console.log(req.file);
  
      cb(null, file.name + ".png");
    },
  });

const imageUpload : Multer = multer({
    storage,
    limits: {
        fileSize: 5000000
    }
});

app.post('/uploadPhoto', imageUpload.single('file'), async (req: express.Request, res:express.Response) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.file);
    res.json({ message: 'Successfully uploaded file' });
    return;
});
```

I omitted some code for space reasons, but for some reason it just won't work. Logged file returns a file, but the backend refuses to see it.

Thanks

- Zach

Comment: FYI Axios doesn't throw exceptions unless you `await` it in an `async` function. When using `.then()`, you should also use `.catch()`, eg `.catch(err => console.error(err.toJSON()))`

Comment: Do you actually use that `fileFilter`? Do you see the `console.log()` from your `filename` hook?

Comment: Which version of redaxios are you using? You need at least [version 0.3.0 to use `FormData`](https://github.com/developit/redaxios/issues/28)

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/rOvhXXT.png - I do have RedAxios 0.4.1 right now, I was using FileFilter but it was causing an error because the file was undefined so I stopped using it for debugging purposes. I will add in a .catch good call

Comment: Could you try a super-simple Multer [in-memory storage](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#memorystorage) implementation with no limits just to see if that part works?

Comment: That does work, so what could be happening?

Comment: So in the network https://i.imgur.com/6lCghKW.png -> this is the request
https://i.imgur.com/082dyyo.png -> this is the payload -> the server just says it's undefined

Comment: Whoops, misread that as _"doesn't work"_. Ok, so the problem is in your Multer configuration. Need to check the docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your Multer DiskStorage configuration is the cause of the problems.

My guess is you have the wrong file paths because `./` is not what you think. This is why it's always good to resolve paths from `__dirname` (the current script's parent directory).

Note that the documentation for `destination` states...

> If a string is passed and the directory does not exist, Multer attempts to create it recursively

So you'll need to manually create the upload directories since you're using the function version.

You also have the wrong argument type in your `filename` hook. The `file` argument is of type `Express.Multer.File`, not `File`. You don't need to set this as it's already defined by the function signature.

```ts
import { resolve } from "path";
import { mkdir } from "fs/promises";
import multer from "multer";

const uploadBase = resolve(__dirname, "./public/photos");

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: async (req, _file, cb) => {
    const path = req.body.id ? resolve(uploadBase, req.body.id) : uploadBase;
    try {
      // create the directory
      await mkdir(path, { recursive: true });
      cb(null, path);
    } catch (err) {
      cb(err);
    }
  },
  filename: (_req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, file.originalname); // note the property used
  }
});
```

Make sure you install `@types/multer` as a dev-dependency to get useful linting in your editor.

Comment: So I went and tried this, the PATH resolves correctly, but now getting ENOENT: No such file or directory, open 'PATH_TO_IMAGE'

https://i.imgur.com/zLV0sAc.png

Comment: Okay so Multer doesn't automatically create destinations if `destination` is a function, only when it's a string.

Comment: @ZachHandley I updated my answer to include upload directory creation

Comment: Appreciated :) thanks for all your help!